# Transfer learning with Keras: Input shape mismatch

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, transfer-learning

I'm running a classification and predition neural network algorithme using pre-trained model with keras. 
Now I know the shape of the input for keras is `(224,224,3)` but my input has this shape `(180, 200, 20)` and I get the following error:

`ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 64. Shapes are [3,3,20,64] and [64,3,3,3]. for 'Assign_32' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [3,3,20,64], [64,3,3,3].`

and here is the code:

```
from keras import applications
from keras.layers import Input

input_tensor = Input(shape = (180, 200, 20))
vgg_model = applications.VGG16(weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False, input_tensor = input_tensor)
vgg_model.summary()
```

Any idea how to get around this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From [Documentation](https://keras.io/applications/#vgg16):

> input_shape: optional shape tuple, only to be specified if include_top
>   is False (otherwise the input shape has to be (224, 224, 3) (with
>   'channels_last' data format) or (3, 224, 224) (with 'channels_first'
>   data format). It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and
>   height should be no smaller than 32. E.g. (200, 200, 3) would be one
>   valid value.

You can try to create a vgg16 from scratch from this link. [VGG16 model for Keras](https://gist.github.com/baraldilorenzo/07d7802847aaad0a35d3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize your input image

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
img = image.load_img("image1.jpeg",target_size=(224,224))
```

If you want to learn to do transfer learning from scratch in keras you can read this article. This article has step by step implementation.
https://medium.com/@1297rohit/transfer-learning-from-scratch-using-keras-339834b153b9

Comment: thank you. But I'm not training my model on images, I'm training it on voxel grids (which are a representation of point cloud data from LiDAR) and I'm trying to see if transfer learning will help me in this case

Comment: You can train using convolution on anything. It is not specific to images

Answer (score 0):

In your case, since you are not dealing with images of the right size (or number of channels) you may want to cut out large parts of the vgg network to still save the information contained in the middle layers, but I am not sure how efficient it would be.

You would need to remove the first convolution layer, and all the dense layers at the end, replacing them with your own layers. You would certainly need to retrain the whole network, so rather than transfer learning you would be doing very smart initialization.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I had the same idea since the output size is not the same, I thought I would take only 10 convolutional layers (from VGG16) and replace the last block and dense layers with my own layers to do the required tasks.